# How to point in Terraform which Cloudfront to use?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+, terraform-template-file

As an example:
I am deploying Terraform module in us-east-1 which will build the infrastructure + cloudfront distribution. Now the same module will be deployed in us-west-1 as part of the Disaster Recovery region. Now since cloudfront it is a global service, how I can point in Terraform module which will be deployed in us-west-1 to use the existing cloudfront?

Comment: Can you include a [mcve] of what you've done so far and then show what errors or problems you get from running it please?

Answer (score 1):

If these are two modules within the same configuration (i.e. both modules are applied with the same `terraform apply` command), then you simply pass the `aws_cloudfront_distribution` resource out of the module where it's created as an `output`, and pass it into the other module as an input parameter. E.g.:

module1/main.tf

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "mydist" {
   ...
}

output "mydist" {
  value = aws_cloudfront_distribution.mydist
}
```

module2/main.tf

```
variable "mydist" {}
```

main.tf

```
module "mod1" {
  ...
}

module "mod2" {
  ...
  mydist = mod1.mydist
}
```

And now you can access the CloudFront distribution resource from within `module2` by using `var.mydist`.

If these are two modules in entirely separate Terraform configurations, you can either:

- Use the [aws_cloudfront_distribution](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/cloudfront_distribution) data source to get the details about a distribution that was created in a separate configuration
- `output` the distribution from the configuration where it's created, then use the [terraform_remote_state](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/state/remote-state-data.html) data source to retrieve the output from the remote state file.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. Last two hints this is what I am looking for.